# Exact Same Code from CodePen Not Working - MDC Not Defined Error

Tags: javascript

I copied this code from [this](https://codepen.io/rustemgareev/pen/NXoqwR) Codepen. However In my console I can see an "mdc not defined" error even though I am linking in the required Javascript. Where am I going wrong with this?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
  <script>src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"</script>
  <script>
      // Instantiate MDC Drawer
    const drawerEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer');
    const drawer = new mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(drawerEl);

    // Instantiate MDC Top App Bar (required)
    const topAppBarEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar');
    const topAppBar = new mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(topAppBarEl);

    topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.querySelector('.main-content'));
    topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
      drawer.open = !drawer.open;
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Top App Bar -->
<header class="mdc-top-app-bar">
    <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
      <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
        <button class="mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon mdc-icon-button material-icons" href="#">menu</button>
        <a class="mdc-top-app-bar__title" href="https://www.webdenim.io" target="_blank" style="color: inherit;">Webdenim</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="app-drawer-layout mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
    <!-- Drawer -->
    <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--dismissible demo-drawer">
      <nav class="mdc-drawer__drawer">
        <nav class="mdc-drawer__content">
          <div id="icon-with-text-demo" class="mdc-list">
            <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>Inbox
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">star</i>Star
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>Sent Mail
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>Drafts
            </a>
          </div>

          <hr class="mdc-list-divider">

          <div class="mdc-list">
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">email</i>All Mail
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">delete</i>Trash
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item demo-drawer-list-item" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">report</i>Spam
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </aside>

    <!-- Content -->
    <main class="mdc-drawer-app-content main-content">
      <div class="demo-image">
        <svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 362 176" width="362px" height="176px" version="1.1" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 362 176" class="docs-homescreen-empty-sites-svg"><g opacity=".08"><path d="m96.7 91.8h-29.4c-2.3 0-4.2 1.9-4.2 4.2v29.4c0 2.3 1.9 4.2 4.2 4.2h29.4c2.3 0 4.2-1.9 4.2-4.2v-29.4c0-2.3-1.9-4.2-4.2-4.2zm-21 29.4h-4.2v-8.4h4.2v8.4zm8.4 0h-4.2v-14.7h4.2v14.7zm8.4 0h-4.2v-21h4.2v21z"></path><rect y="85.5" x="56.8" height="50.4" width="50.4" fill="none"></rect><rect y="69.5" x="-1" height="26.5" width="26.5" fill="none"></rect><path d="m20 72.8h-15.5c-1.2 0-2.2 1-2.2 2.2v15.4c0 1.2 1 2.2 2.2 2.2h15.5c1.2 0 2.2-1 2.2-2.2v-15.4c0-1.2-1-2.2-2.2-2.2zm-2.2 6.6h-11v-2.2h11v2.2zm0 4.5h-11v-2.2h11v2.2zm-3.4 4.4h-7.7v-2.2h7.7v2.2z"></path><path d="m330 109.6h-29.4c-2.3 0-4.2 1.9-4.2 4.2v29.4c0 2.3 1.9 4.2 4.2 4.2h29.4c2.3 0 4.2-1.9 4.2-4.2v-29.4c0-2.3-1.9-4.2-4.2-4.2zm-21.1 29.5h-4.2v-4.2h4.2v4.2zm0-8.5h-4.2v-4.2h4.2v4.2zm0-8.4h-4.2v-4.2h4.2v4.2zm16.9 16.9h-14.8v-4.2h14.7v4.2zm0-8.5h-14.8v-4.2h14.7v4.2zm0-8.4h-14.8v-4.2h14.7v4.2z"></path><rect y="103.3" x="290" height="50.5" width="50.5" fill="none"></rect><rect y="66.1" x="330.8" height="30.2" width="30.2" fill="none"></rect><path d="m354.7 69.9h-17.6c-1.4 0-2.5 1.1-2.5 2.5v17.6c0 1.4 1.1 2.5 2.5 2.5h17.6c1.4 0 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5v-17.6c0-1.4-1.1-2.5-2.5-2.5zm-17.6 18.9l4.4-6.9 3.2 4.9 4.3-6.8 5.7 8.8h-17.6z"></path><rect y="103.9" x="29.9" height="19.2" width="19.2" fill="none"></rect><path d="m45.1 106.3h-11.2c-0.9 0-1.6 0.7-1.6 1.6v2.4 8.8c0 0.9 0.7 1.6 1.6 1.6h11.2c0.9 0 1.6-0.7 1.6-1.6v-11.2c0-0.9-0.8-1.6-1.6-1.6zm0 6.4h-6.4v6.4h-1.6v-6.4h-3.2v-1.6h3.2v-3.2h1.6v3.2h6.4v1.6z"></path><g id="Icon_1_"><rect y="39.2" x="35.1" height="32.7" width="32.7" fill="none"></rect><path d="m62.4 45.2c-0.8-0.3-5.9-0.5-10.9-0.5s-10.1 0.3-11 0.5c-2.2 0.7-2.7 5.5-2.7 10.4s0.5 9.7 2.7 10.4c0.8 0.3 5.9 0.5 10.9 0.5s10.1-0.3 10.9-0.5c2.2-0.7 2.7-5.5 2.7-10.4s-0.5-9.7-2.6-10.4zm-13.7 16.5v-12.2l8.2 6.1-8.2 6.1z"></path></g><path d="m296.8 51h-21.2c-1.7 0-3 1.4-3 3v21.2c0 1.7 1.3 3 3 3h21.2c1.7 0 3-1.4 3-3v-21.1c0-1.7-1.3-3.1-3-3.1zm0 19.7h-21.2v-12.1h21.2v12.1z"></path><rect y="46.5" x="268.1" height="36.3" width="36.3" fill="none"></rect></g><g opacity=".1"><path d="m283.1 22.7c0-2.8-2.3-5.1-5.1-5.1h-177c-2.8 0-5.1 2.3-5.1 5.1v134.8c0 2.8 2.3 5.1 5.1 5.1h177c2.8 0 5.1-2.3 5.1-5.1v-134.8z" fill="#232421"></path></g><path d="m283.1 20.7c0-2.8-2.3-5.1-5.1-5.1h-177c-2.8 0-5.1 2.3-5.1 5.1v134.8c0 2.8 2.3 5.1 5.1 5.1h177c2.8 0 5.1-2.3 5.1-5.1v-134.8z" fill="#F1F1F1"></path><path d="m278.5 14h-177.4c-2.9 0-5.3 2.3-5.3 5.1v15.6h187.3v-15.6c0-2.8-1.7-5.1-4.6-5.1" fill="#A5A5A4"></path><rect y="22" x="134.8" height="6" width="120.4" fill="#E9E9E9"></rect><polygon points="107.8 22 104.8 25 107.8 28" fill="#E9E9E9"></polygon><polygon points="113.8 28 116.8 25 113.8 22" fill="#E9E9E9"></polygon><path d="m122.8 25c0 1.7 1.3 3 3 3s3-1.3 3-3-1.3-3-3-3-3 1.3-3 3" fill="#E9E9E9"></path><rect y="22" x="267.1" height="6" width="6" fill="#E9E9E9"></rect><rect y="41.6" x="114.5" height="84" width="150" fill="#E1E1E1"></rect><rect y="133" x="115" height="28" width="71" fill="#E1E1E1"></rect><rect y="133" x="195" height="7" width="70" fill="#E1E1E1"></rect><rect y="145" x="195" height="6" width="70" fill="#E1E1E1"></rect><rect y="156" x="195" height="5" width="70" fill="#E1E1E1"></rect><rect y="75" x="147" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="69" x="147" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="69" x="153" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="75" x="153" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="75" x="221" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="69" x="221" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="69" x="227" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="75" x="227" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="93" x="193" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="87" x="199" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="87" x="175" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="93" x="187" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="93" x="181" height="6" width="6" fill="#A3A3A3"></rect><rect y="81.3" x="226.2" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="81.3" x="140.7" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="81.3" x="232.2" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="81.3" x="220.2" height="6" width="6" fill="#fff"></rect><rect y="81.3" x="146.7" height="6" width="12" fill="#fff"></rect><polygon points="73.2 29 67.8 23.6 73.2 18.2 78.6 23.6" fill="#fff"></polygon><polygon points="282.3 5.7 279.7 3.1 282.3 0.6 284.8 3.1" fill="#fff"></polygon><rect transform="matrix(.7068 .7074 -.7074 .7068 157.46 -184.43)" height="4.7" width="4.7" y="95.4" x="298.9" fill="#fff"></rect><rect transform="matrix(.7074 .7069 -.7069 .7074 136.08 -10.343)" height="6.1" width="6.1" y="156.1" x="77.5" fill="#fff"></rect><polygon points="333.7 55.6 328.3 50.2 333.7 44.9 339 50.2" fill="#fff"></polygon><polygon points="14.8 108.5 12.2 106 14.8 103.4 17.3 106" fill="#fff"></polygon><polygon points="341.7 150.9 339.1 148.3 341.7 145.8 344.3 148.3" fill="#fff"></polygon><rect transform="matrix(.7071 .7071 -.7071 .7071 73.277 -28.003)" height="4.5" width="4.5" y="72.2" x="68.2" fill="#fff"></rect></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="demo__title">Click the menu button</div>
      <div class="demo__subtitle"> at the top left of the page to toggle the drawer</div>
    </main>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: No I am just using html and css

Comment: `<script>src="http...` your script tag has a typo you added a `>` in the wrong place, before the src attribute ending that tag too early. It should be after the last `"` Thus the library file is not being loaded. After which you are going to run into this problem [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element/8716680) as you run your code too early

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with script injections

```
<script>src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"</script>
```

its should be

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: HTML head block execute first and then BODY block, if you get/set any element it will be the problem, it's better you can add JS code at the bottom or after document complete event(if you want to do some code in the head)